# can i write this $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \psi(\textbf{x}) \, d^{2}\textbf{x} = 2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \rho \, \phi(\rho)\, d\rho $?

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

If the function $\psi$ is isotropic, (i.e.  $\psi(\textbf{x}) = \phi(|\textbf{x}|)$, where $\phi \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, then can i write
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:2.1}
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \psi(\textbf{x}) \, d^{2}\textbf{x} = 2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \rho \, \phi(\rho)\, d\rho ,   
\end{equation}
where $\rho=|\textbf{x}|$ is the norm of $\textbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}?$

Answer (score 0):

You can view it as a substation,
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\psi(x,y)dxdy$$
Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$.(i.e. polar coordinates) for which the jacobian is known to be $r$.
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \phi(r^2)r~dr~d\theta$$

$$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int^\infty_0 \phi(r^2)r~dr~d\theta$$
now, doing simple substitution $r^2=\rho$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int^\infty_0 \phi(\rho)d\rho d\theta$$
Because the integral inside isn't dependent on $\theta$ then it is equal to
$$2\pi\int^\infty_0 \phi(\rho)d\rho$$

### 3D

$$\iiint_{\mathbb R^3}\psi(x,y,z)dxdydz$$
using spherical coordinates:
$$\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_0\int^\infty_0\phi(r^2)r\sin(\theta)drd\theta d\alpha$$
$$2\pi\int_0^\pi sin(\theta)d\theta \int_0^\infty\phi(r^2)rdr$$
$$4\pi\int^\infty_0 \phi(\rho)d\rho$$
I'm unsure of the existence of a general solution.

Comment: thank u so much , it will be very helpful in my research work.

Comment: You need anything else about it?

Comment: Sir, in place of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ if we take $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then what will be the result?